# Trim fields in Json using Scala transforms?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Given that I have a Json structure as follows:

```
{
    "id" : "1B23423B",
    "payload" : {
        "list" : [ {
            "name" : "test",
            "data" : [ {
                "value" : "Some html",
                "type" : "html",
            }, {
                "value" : "some text",
                "type" : "text"
            }]
         }]
    }
}
```

Is there some smart way in which I can convert an array of strings containing field names to Scala transforms, without having to manually specify the transform for each string value.

E.g., I'd like the strings ("id", "value") to return:

```
{
    "id" : "1B23423B",
    "payload" : {
        "list" : [ {
            "data" : [ {
                "value" : "Some html",
            }, {
                "value" : "some text",
            }]
         }]
    }
}
```

("data") would return:

```
{
    "payload" : {
        "list" : [ {
            "data" : [ {
                "value" : "Some html",
                "type" : "html",
            }, {
                "value" : "some text",
                "type" : "text"
            }]
         }]
    }
}
```

And so on. Hope my intent is clear - basically, I want to use the string array as a projection over a Json structure. The actual structure is much larger (20+ fields), which is why I'd prefer not to have to map each transform from the string "manually".

I'm currently using Play's Json library for everything, so preferably something that works within that framework.

Comment: What about using `transform` method with function that fits your business cases? (that function will traverse the tree and modify it as you want)

Comment: Wouldn't I have to create a transform for each possible entry in the string array? That's what I'd like to avoid.